# Do search engine bots - crawlers - spiders - etc. have javascript in them?

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, search-engine-bots

I don't know how search engine bots work, database entries for robots on my browser records are e.g. Googlebot, msnbot, BingBot, etc.

So I don't know if they have javascript enabled or anything.

Why I want to know if they have javascript enabled? Because I want to require Javascript on my site. What I did to do this is that I have an 'overlay' div with a short message that I set to 'display:none' with javascript on page load. So if there is no Javascript the overlay won't dissapear and nothing in the site is clickable or anything.

So can robots still crawl my site even with the Javascript requirement thing I made? Because I want google and other good bots to be able to crawl my site.

Comment: Yes. They don't see the site.  They parse the html content.  And yes, it is possible for them to spider through javascript files emulating real users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search robots can and will crawl your site, but they do not understand JavaScript, so they will ignore any JS. They should however have no issue crawling the page you described.

Comment: You should mention that some bots are beginning to execute some JavaScript, but it's by no means standard

Comment: In fact the Google-bot is pretty darn good at "running" JS-Code!

Comment: @Walialu From my personal experience, Google has been unable to parse JS on my site whatsoever.

Comment: In your opinion would the page described above be penalize in SEO and trustworthiness or something?

Comment: @AppleDash The google-bot was always able to "run" my JavaScript code. This was pretty easy to test, as I was attaching different CSS-Styles with different background-images and so on, based on the screen-size. Was executed as expected by the google-bot ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since 2010 at least googlebot was known for understanding not direct links created in (some) javascript, but they won't need your javascript to read links, as those are plainly visible in html. The same goes with people browsing with javascript turned off.

Comment: Indeed, a bot doesn't _see_ a popup that blocks the rest of the page. They just see the html.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know search engines can parse content recognizing different content and behavior. They can also penalize specific hiding content. I suspect Google is a very smart search engine and has the ability to recognize some javascript but the internal behavior of their system is unknown to us.

Comment: Would the trick I made above to require JS be categorized as 'hiding content'?

Comment: As long as you use for functional purposes it's ok. Just don't fill the hidden content with a lot of keywords for example.